# Powershell unzip zip file having large number of files

Tags: powershell, unzip

I'm trying to unzip the zipped file. I've written the code as follows

```
function Unzip($sourceZip, $destination) {

        $shell = new-object -com shell.application
        $zip = $shell.NameSpace($sourceZip)
        $dest = $shell.NameSpace($destination)
        foreach($item in $zip.items())
        {
            $dest.Copyhere($item, 0x14) 
        }
}
```

I'm calling this script on the input zip file which contain around 14K files as below

```
Unzip "Source.zip" "Destination"
```

This file gets stuck for more than 30 minutes. And still no progress.

From what I've find out it gets at this line `$zip.items()` It might be taking large time to discover all the files.

Is there any better, optimal way to do this??

Thanks in advance. Regards, Ganesh.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it using System.IO.Compression (requires .net 4.5):

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.IO.Compression.FileSystem')
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($sourceZip, $destination)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could install something like [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) which has command line tools to do this sort of thing but I don't know of any better native way.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't install 7zip on every computer that'll run this script

Comment: Doesn't have to install, there's a standalone console version that you could stick on a network drive somewhere, if you can't copy it to every computer. But I'd go this route as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [string]
    $Source,

    [string]
    $Destination
)

Write-Verbose "Loading System.IO.Compression.FileSystem Assembly"
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.IO.Compression.FileSystem')

Write-Verbose "Unpacking $Source to $Destination"
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($Source, $Destination)
```

but it require .net4.5 +